# Why is React Router causing my components to re-mount, rather than just re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am creating an app using react router, with several routes including a `Uploader` component where videos are uploaded, and a `Videos` component where they are viewed. The video page stores some comments as state, which i want to remain on the page throughout the app being open. However, react router seems to be causing each component to re-mount rather than re-render, causing my state to be reset to the intial empty values whenever i re-route back to the `Video` component. I'm using the `render` method rather than the `component` method inside my `Route` components, so i don't understand why this is happening. Does anyone know whats causing this?

Here is the main app where routing occurs:

```
class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        var fileNames
        var files
        var fileSelected
        this.state={fileSelected:null}
     }

    getFileFromChild= (uploadedFiles)=> {
         this.files = uploadedFiles

    }

    fileButtonClicked= (index)=> {
        //extract file chosen by user based on button click
        this.setState({fileSelected: this.files[0][index]})

    }

    render(){
        //destructuring props in class component
        const {user} = this.props;
    return(

        <Router>
            <div className = "nav-bar">
                <Nav/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact render={()=> <HomePage />
                    }/> 
                    <Route path='/videos' render={()=> <Videos files= {this.files} fileSelected={this.state.fileSelected}/>
                    }/>
                    <Route path='/uploader' render={()=> <Uploader  passFile= {this.getFileFromChild} fileButtonClicked={this.fileButtonClicked}/>
                    } />
                </Switch>


            </div>

        </Router>
    )
    }
}
```

Here is the `Videos` component where the state i need is stored:

```
class Videos extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.videoRef = React.createRef();
    }

    // once DOM loads get video tag and reload it
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.videoRef.current.load()
    }

    render(){
        const {files, fileSelected}=this.props;
        var src = (fileSelected) ? URL.createObjectURL(fileSelected): URL.createObjectURL(files[0][0])

        return( 
                <div>
                    <div className="ui one column centered grid">
                        <div className="one wide column"> {/*needs to be one wide here not just column for center to work*/}
                            <h3>Videos</h3>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div className="ui grid">
                        <div className="ten wide column">
                            <video ref={this.videoRef} controls width="566" height="320">
                                    <source src={src} id='video' type="video/mp4" />
                                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                            </video>
                            <CommentsSection/>

                        </div>

                        <div className="six wide column">
                            {files[1]}
                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>

            )


    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't exactly get what you mean by "when the `Video` component is loaded more than once" but let me see if I can answer your question.

If you're saying that the `Video` component is unmounted and mounted when you navigate(change route) away and back to it - resulting in losing the state of the `Video` component you had - that **is the expected behaviour** of the `render` method of `Route`.

Let me explain in regards to the official docs on the react router page:

> *When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
> given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
> component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
> results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
> mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
> an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
> children prop...*

What this means is:

- component passed into either `render` or `component` prop will always unmount and mount **on route change**
- if you pass an inline component into the `render` prop, **it will not** unmount and remount on every render - it will "remember" the inline function and not perform mount/unmount
- if you passed an inline component into the `component` prop, **it will** unmount and mount on every render - it will re-create the inline component on every render so it performs the unmounting of the old instance of the component and mounting of the newly created instance of the component

Takeaways:

- both `component` and `render` props will unmount on navigating away, and mount on navigating in, and that is the expected and desired behaviour.
- you pass an inline component into `render` prop (e.g `<Route render={() => <HomePage />}`)
- you pass a component into `component` prop (e.g `<Route component={HomePage} />`)
- never pass inline components into `component` prop
- in your case, you're using the `render` component correctly. You just got confused with unmount and mounts on route change vs. prop change

Comment: yes that is what i meant. However, im not using the `component` here, im using `render` so surely i shouldnt see this behaviour?

Comment: Don't be confused between mounting/unmount on route change vs. prop change. The official docs is trying to state that `component` unmounts/mounts on prop change but `render` doesn't unmount/mount of prop change. Both unmounts/mounts on route change. By "every render" in the official docs is **not** referring to route change -- rather the change in props (which triggers the rendering).

Comment: I've spend  10+ hours trying to rewrite my app in a way that allows me have routing-aware components that don't have unwanted state resets, and after reading this I realized that all I had to do was replace the `component` prop with `render`. Thank you!